# having trouble with if(!empty mysql not working

Tags: mysql, post, if-statement, is-empty

```
if(!empty($_POST['client_name']) && !empty($_POST['ref_no']) && !empty($_POST['assigned_engr']) &&     !empty($_POST['purpose']))
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `summary_item`(`date_out`, `client`, `reference_no`,     `item`, `comcode`, `serial_no1`, `purpose`, `assigned_engineer`, `status`) VALUES ('".date("F d,   Y")."','".$_POST['client_name']."','".$_POST['ref_no']."','".$row['classification']."','".$row['comcode']."','".$_SESSION['STF_DELIVERY_ITEMS']  [$i]."','".$_POST['purpose']."','".$_POST['assigned_engr']."','PENDING')");
    }
}
```

i'm not the programmer in our system so i don't know how to change and remove the if(!empty statement
i wish to remove this code so that there will be no required fields. please help. i know that i should remove the if(!empty but when i do so i get an error cause i still have a code like this

```
<td style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;"><strong><span id="client_address_span"><?php if(!empty($_POST['caddr'])) { echo $_POST['caddr']; } ?>
```

and when i also remove the if(!empty and leave the code like this

```
<td style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;"><strong><span id="client_address_span"><?php echo $_POST['caddr']; ?>
```

it doesn't work. it won't add to the database. please i really need help to finish this inventory system.